# What is the difference between <<history>> and <<bag>> stereotype in UML?

Tags: java, uml, history, bag

I need to implement examples of `<<history>>` and `<<bag>>` stereotype in Java, but the every article I have read difference between them is not explained. Could you please explain it, or show some code which explains it all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it is said(not in english) that the implementation is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

`{bag}` and `<<history>>` are very similiar. The difference is that `<<history>>` should be use to keep a record of changes in time.

Also keep in mind that `{bag}` is a constraint while `<<history>>` is a stereotype.